# How to select from two tables with IF?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 table in my DB, first is `users`, and second is `friends`.

In the `users` tables I have a column named `friend' this columns have a random ID of each one, and this ID you used for calling someone to subscribe with your URL.

but if an old person want to become your friend I add other table named `friends`

content the random ID + ID_USER

now, I want to `SELECT * FROM users, friends WHERE users.friends = 'BlaBla' OR friends.RANDOMID = 'BlaBla'`

I try with this code, but I doesn't work, it's give all persons having the random 
in calling friend

```
SELECT * 
FROM users, friends
WHERE users.Role =  "User"
AND users.call = :random
OR (users.ID = friends.ID_USER
AND friends.random =  :random)
```

Any solution?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Use `join` and `on` syntax. The `where` should be how you want to filter the records, not how the `join` should be done. The PHP tag also seems irrelevant, this is just mysql, no?

Comment: @CésarEscudero; I want exactly sir: get all data from table if call = 'someting' if not verify on the second table.

Comment: @user3783243 yes it's just mysql